# Java file input split

Tags: java

I have a file containing 3 lines:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

If at some point I have

```
String line = input.readline(); 
String[] nums = line.split(" ");
```

Will nums contain a "\n" string at the end? (is the size of nums going to be 3 or 4?)

Comment: Why don't you just try and see for yourself?

Comment: Or you could also [take a look at the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will nums contain a "\n" string at the end? (is the size of nums going
> to be 3 or 4?)

No. The length of `nums` will be 3.

Also, `Scanner` does not have a method called, `readline`. The correct method is `nextLine`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"))) {
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = input.nextLine();
                String[] nums = line.split(" ");
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
                System.out.println(nums.length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3]
3
[4, 5, 6]
3
[7, 8, 9]
3
```